# printf("%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1)); meets a segmentation fault

Tags: lua

Why this code snippet encounter a segmentation fault?

```
 luaL_dostring(L, "print('this is a test')");
 printf("%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
```

Here are the error message and backtrace:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. strlen () at
> ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106 106     ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S: No
> such file or directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chunk that you execute doesn't return anything. Assuming that your stack is empty at the moment you call `luaL_dostring`, it stays the same way after you call it. This means that when you call `lua_tostring(L, -1)`, you call it against an empty stack and so SEGV is encountered:

```c
lua_State * L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);
// stack is empty
luaL_dostring(L, "print('this is a test')");
// stack is still empty
printf("%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1)); // segmentation fault
```

For comparison you can try:

```c
luaL_dostring(L, "print('this is a test') return 'another string'");
printf("%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1)); // prints: another string
```

To prevent such errors, **always** check values you want to use:

```c
luaL_dostring(L, "print('this is a test')");
if (lua_isstring(L, -1))
   printf("%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1)); // OK, line is not executed
```

You can also check the return value of [`lua_tolstring`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_tolstring):

```c
const char * value = lua_tostring(L, -1);
if (NULL != value)
   printf("%s\n", value); // Also OK
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The output message(i.e: 'this is a test') has never been pushed to the stack (when invoking "print('this is a test')"), it's just printed to the stdout by the `fwrite() `(invoked by `lua_writeline()`) function. Am I right?

Comment: @John, Yes, pretty much, on top of that print/[`luaB_print`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lbaselib.c.html#luaB_print) doesn't push anything to stack at all. Try: `type(print("whatever"))` and compare with `type(nil)`.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of comparing `type(print("whatever"))` and `type(nil)`. And I get error messages when invoking `type(print("whatever"))`.Here are the outputs and error messages:"> type(print("whatever"))
whatever
stdin:1: bad argument #1 to 'type' (value expected)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'type'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?"

Comment: @John, Point was to illustrate that behaviour differs between returning `nil` and returning nothing at all. And it's worth remembering that `print` doesn't return anything as it can cause problems in some very rare cases. From Lua side it doesn't happen often as `nil` is almost omnipresent and `tostring` handles all types, but when you use C API you may shoot yourself in a foot.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume it's because there's no string at the top of the stack after your Lua code completes.

Comment: I think you are right. But `print('this is a test')` actually outputs a message when you invoke it in Lua. That's where I am confusing.

Comment: Well, yes, the code that fails comes after the `luaL_dostring`, so of course that part still works.